# Why does Ruby call the `call` method when I don't supply the method name?

Tags: ruby

Given the following module:

```
module Foo
  def self.call
    'foo'
  end
end
```

I would of course expect the following to work:

```
puts Foo.call  # outputs "foo"
```

However, I did not expect this to work:

```
puts Foo.()    # outputs "foo"
```

Apparently when the method name is left off, Ruby assumes that I want to call the `call` method.  Where is this documented, and why does it behave that way?

Comment: Which Ruby version is this?

Comment: Can be reproduced at least with JRuby 1.7.3.

Comment: Confirmed in MRI 2.0.

Comment: I just tried it in MRI 1.9.3, haven't tried an earlier version.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`Proc#call`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Proc.html#method-i-call):

> Invokes the block, setting the block’s parameters to the values in params using something close to method calling semantics. Generates a warning if multiple values are passed to a proc that expects just one (previously this silently converted the parameters to an array). ***Note that prc.() invokes prc.call() with the parameters given. It’s a syntax sugar to hide “call”.***

I did some research and found method `#()` is a syntactic sugar of the method `#call`..Look at the error as below :

```
module Foo
  def self.bar
    12
  end
end
Foo.()
#undefined method `call' for Foo:Module (NoMethodError)
```

As OP defined the `#call` method in module `Foo` class,`Foo#call` is called in an attempt of `Foo.()`.

Here is some more examples :

```
"ab".method(:size).() # => 2
"ab".method(:size).call # => 2
"ab".() # undefined method `call' for "ab":String (NoMethodError)
```

See here what *Matz* said [*So compromise with object.() syntax introduced in 1.9...*](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4407820#1084230)

Comment: How do you overwrite `Proc#call` if you are in a plain module?

Comment: @tessi I don't think you are, but I guess this applies to the `call` method in general even though it was implemented for this reason alone.  Thanks for sharing this, @ArupRakshit!

Comment: @PerLundberg You're right that I'm not overriding `Proc#call`, but I think Arup's narrowed it down quite a bit.  The quote from the doc makes it sound like this was put in place for the `Proc#call`, but it works for any `call` method in general.  I'll leave the question open for a bit longer though to see if there is anymore feedback.

Comment: Ah, I was a bit too quick in my judgment also (trying to find the answer myself as fast a spossible ;) so I removed my silly comment (which you replied to). Nonetheless, he found a reasonably good reference which said something about it, which is good.

Comment: FWIW, I didn't interpret the "syntactic sugar" comment as being specific to this object/method. I took it to mean that `.()` is turned into `.call()` in the parser. I wonder if it's documented there ....

Comment: It's pretty much impossible for Ruby to define syntactic sugar that only applies to one type since Ruby is dynamically typed. Syntactic sugar applies to all types equally, though it may not make sense with the object's type at runtime.

Comment: @Chuck In the `Proc#call` documentation it explicitly mentioned abou the feature.

Comment: Link is broken :( :(

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, as Arup is saying, this is syntactic sugar introduced a while ago, possibly for the single cause of making `Proc` objects easier to work with. (You don't have to explicitly call them, but can just do `prc.()` instead).

I also concluded that this is definitely a Ruby 1.9+ feature. If I switch my JRuby to 1.8 mode, I get this instead:

```
SyntaxError: spam.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected tLPAREN2
```

So, somewhere in the changelogs for Ruby 1.9 it can probably be found, if someone really wants to dig it out from the caves... :)